# jstl core for Each over heterogeneous collection

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

i have a controller returning  to a JSP page an object of type `ArrayList` of type `MyClass`.
The objects inside the ArrayList belong to different classes, let's say `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` each one of them extending MyClass. I am able to iterate over the collection with the forEach tag and get the current element type thanks to the field `type` in `MyClass` but when i try to access to a specific field of `MyClass1` i got this error.

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'noContentMessage' not found on type it.sei.core.rinterface.MyClass1`.

Here is my code:

```
class MyClass {
    String type;
    String variable;
}

class MyClass1 extends MyClass{
    String someOtherField;
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass{
    String noContentMessage;
}



<core:forEach items="${model.GraphList}" var="element" varStatus="index"> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 var  type = '${element.type}';
 switch (type)
            {
                case "type1":
                    {
                       var variable = '${element.variable}';

                    }
                    break;

                case "type2":
                    {
                       var message = '${element.noContentMessage}';

                    }
                    break;
             }
             </script>   
          </core:forEach>
```

So why is this happening? Is not possible in JSTL to handle this situation?

Comment: Show us the getters of the class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSP EL never accesses fields. Only properties, i.e. public getters.

Add a public getter for the fields that you want to use from the JSP EL:

```
public String getNoContentMessage() {
    return this.noContentMessage;
}
```

EDIT:

Also, your switch block is JavaScript code, executed at client side, long after the page has been generated. For the JSP engine, the JavaScript code is plain text, and all the branches of your switch block are generated. So, for every object in the collection, all the JSP EL expressions are evaluated.

The code should be rewritten as

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     var  type = '${element.type}'; // is it necessary?
     <c:if test="${element.type == 'type1'}">
         var variable = '${element.variable}';
     </c:if>
     <c:if test="${element.type == 'type2'}">
         var message = '${element.noContentMessage}';
     </c:if>
</script>
```

although I don't understand how it makes sense to redefine the same JS variable, again and again, for every of the elements in the collection.

Comment: This solved it! Turns oit that the problem was with the switch block. Thanks for your help!